# How to map a key to insert multiple lines of code or comments?

Tags: vim

I want to map a key or a key combination, ideally `fg` to insert a template for function headers.

How can I map `fg` in the Vim's insert mode to insert for example the following code into my file:

```
/*
 * Function Name: 
 * Description: 
 * Parameters: 
 * Result: 
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend mapping `fg` in insert mode since `f` is a character that you normally type in. Mapping `fg` creates two possible outcomes for `f` character: one - actually a `f` character being added at the position of the cursor and another - call mapped macros. That is why each time you type in `f` vim will wait for the next character to check if it is not `g` if it is not then it will add that next character but if you type just `f` vim will wait small amount of time and only then release the cursor. It feels like vim is lagging.

I prefer to make that mapping for normal mode but make it switch to insert mode:

```
nnoremap fg i/*<CR>Function Name:<CR>Description:<CR>Parameter:<CR>Result:<CR>/<CR>
```

Comment: @gitlinux If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Answer (score 0):

`ino fg /*<CR>Function Name: <CR> Description: <CR> Parameter:<CR> Result:<CR>/`

You might need some minor adjustments for the formatting

Answer (score 0):

If you want an on the fly solution instead of a .vimrc one you can always use a macro:

1. Enter the normal mode.
2. Type `q`.
3. Type any letter you want to record the macro into (let's say it's `f`).
4. Enter the insert mode and just type in the template you would like to record.
5. Exit the insert mode and click `q` to stop recording.
6. Now you can use paste the text you've recorded under the letter `f` whenever you type `@f`.